# ASP.MVC3: are there 3 MvcApplication instances when debugging?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Is MvcApplication singleton in a MVC 3 Web Application? Why did I find 3 instances?

My steps: (VS2010 SP1 + ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update)

1. create a default Internet MVC 3 Appliction (with the account sample)
2. Add a MvcApplication() constructor in global.asax, and set a breakpoint in it
3. Press F5 to debug

I found the constructor was called 3 times!

Best regards,

Zach@Shine

===Edit===

Correction:

2 instances, not 3 were found for 1 web app. 
After a careful check, I found my solution contains 2 web apps, after I removed one of them, I can find 2 instances for the left app.

Here is the log (the numbers are the MvcApplication instances' hashcode)

```
MvcApplication(): 41516761
Application_Start(): 41516761
 MvcApplication(): 56552081
 Application_AuthenticateRequest(): 56552081
 Application_AuthenticateRequest(): 56552081
 Application_AuthenticateRequest(): 56552081
 MvcApplication_Disposed(): 56552081
Application_End(): 41516761
```

As shown, one instance is used to handle Start, End events, and the other one is used to handle requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MvcApplication inherits from HttpApplication from the normal asp.net below is a great link to understanding the asp.net pipeline. I have copied the relevant section from the article.

In short - no MvcApplication is not singleton but there is only ever one present with each request.

http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp

> Each request is routed to an HttpApplication object. The
>   HttpApplicationFactory class creates a pool of HttpApplication objects
>   for your ASP.NET application depending on the load on the application
>   and hands out references for each incoming request. The size of the
>   pool is limited to the setting of the MaxWorkerThreads setting in
>   machine.config’s ProcessModel Key, which by default is 20.   The pool
>   starts out with a smaller number though; usually one and it then grows
>   as multiple simulataneous requests need to be processed. The Pool is
>   monitored so under load it may grow to its max number of instances,
>   which is later scaled back to a smaller number as the load drops.  
>   HttpApplication is the outer container for your specific Web
>   application and it maps to the class that is defined in Global.asax.
>   It’s the first entry point into the HTTP Runtime that you actually see
>   on a regular basis in your applications. If you look in Global.asax
>   (or the code behind class) you’ll find that this class derives
>   directly from HttpApplication: